# JSF 2: page redirect after ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, navigation

I'm stuck in a navigation case problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920112/jsf-2-0-a-navigation-case) one.
In a few words, I'm trying to redirect navigation from one page to another, using an ajax rendered `h:commandLink`.
Here's the backing bean

```
@ManagedBean
public class StartBean {

    public void search(){
        FacesContext
            .getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext()
            .getFlash()
            .put("result", "hooray!")
        ;
    }

    public String showResult(){
        return "result?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

and the starting page

```
<h:body>
    <h:form prependId="false">
        <h:commandButton value="Click" action="#{startBean.search}">
            <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    
        <br/>
         
        <h:commandLink 
            action="#{startBean.showResult()}" 
            rendered="#{flash.result != null}" 
            value="#{flash.result}"
        />
    
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

whereas `result` page is just showing a message. Both pages are on web module context root.
It happens that the `h:commandLink` is correctly displayed after ajax submit, but clicking on it causes a page refresh. It doesn't redirect towards the `result` page, as expected.
After it, if page is reloaded (F5), `result` page is shown. It seems to be a rendering cycle matter.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `rendered` attribute of all input and command components is **re-evaluated** when the form is submitted. So if it evaluates `false`, then JSF simply won't invoke the action. The Flash scope is terminated when the request/response of the `search()` method is finished. It isn't there in the Flash scope anymore when you send the request of the `showResult()`. I suggest to put the bean in the view scope and bind the `rendered` attribute to its property instead.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class StartBean {

    private String result;

    public void search(){
        result = "hooray";
    }

    public String showResult(){
        return "result?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

}
```

with

```
<h:commandLink 
    action="#{startBean.showResult}" 
    rendered="#{startBean.result != null}" 
    value="#{startBean.result}"
/>
```

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)